# Axios Response in React Page

Tags: django, reactjs, axios, material-ui

I am trying to set the state of my Axios Response data. The REST call works but the state is not being set.

```
this.state = {
  source: sources['bunnyMovie'],
  startDate : moment(),
  endDate: moment(),//endDate : moment()
  filename: "",
  storageArea: [],
  v_bucketName: "",
  v_creationDate: "",
};
componentDidMount() {
const self = this;
axios.get(`/api/Storage/`)
  .then(response => {
    self.setState({storageArea: response.data});
    console.log(response);
    console.log("StorageArea: " + self.storageArea);
  });
```

}

```
 <option value="" />
                    {this.state.storageArea.map((Buckets, i) => (
                      <option native="true" key={i} value={Buckets.Name}>
                        {Buckets.Name}
                      </option>
```

But the storageArea is null. Incidentally, the type can be array or was NULL before I changed it. Either way it's not working. What am I missing?

Comment: That should be `self.state.storageAge` not `self.storageAge`

Answer (score 0):

You can can access the storageArea with

```
this.state.storageArea
```

anyway the state will be updated asynchronously, so you may want to do

```
console.log(this.state.storageArea)
```

in render method, rather that right after setState

Comment: Sorry I'm not following. storageArea is not even getting set. Are you saying to set it we use your code in the first line?

Answer (score 0):

First, change your console output to `self.state.storageAge`

Next, I would recommend that you test the state change in the `render()` method instead of directly after calling `setState`. This is because React re-renders all components every time `setState` is called.

As per the React docs:

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

Comment: So I updated the code to show an option value being populated from this call. I do this call in ComponentWilMount. I am definitely missing something because the object is still null.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned `setState` is asynchronous, so if you want to log the updated state you need to call `console.log` after the update is completed. 
 Doing it inside the `render` method would work, I find calling it inside the `setState` callback cleaner though. 
 `self.setState({storageArea: response.data},() => console.log(self.state.storageArea))`